# Karate framework:Double quotes missing while printing JSON

Tags: json, karate

```
        * def temp = 23657876
        * def payload =
        [
         [
          {
           "Key" : "first",
           "Value" : "#(temp)"
          }
         ]
        ]
        And print payload
```

This is only printing as below

```
[
 [
  {
    "Key" : "first",
    "Value" : 23657876
  }
 ]
```

Double quotes are missing in print output.
I need to used this payload in a SQL and it's inserting value without quotes which is not a correct JSON
Please guide me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. Value is a JSON `number`.

If you need quotes, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

```
* def temp = '23657876'
```